# How to remove compton from Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: compton

How can I remove compton from Ubuntu 23.04

```
which compton
/usr/local/bin/compton
```

And with

```
apt list | grep compton    
compton 1-1 [Ubuntu/lunar universe]
compton-conf 0.16.0-1ubuntu1 [Ubuntu/lunar universe]
```

But when I tried to remove

> Package 'compton' is not installed, so not removed

Thanks

Comment: When using `apt list`, installed packages are marked `[installed]`. Your output shows that those packages aren't so marked. So it was installed using some other method.

Comment: @user535733 I see. Then is there anyway to find which package brought  compton along with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary `compton` on your system was not installed using the APT package manager. This can be seen

1. because the output of `apt list | grep compton` does not feature `[installed]`
2. because the executable resides in `/usr/local/bin/`, whereas APT managed binaries will be installed under `/usr/bin` or `/usr/sbin`.

Packages may end up under `/usr/local/bin/` as a result of an install script (`sudo make install` after compiling source code, for example) or may have manually been copied there. Only the administrator of your system can tell specifically how the package was installed.

If the package that was installed featured an uninstall script, you can use that to remove the program. Else, you will need to manually remove the installed files. The tool `whereis` may list other installed files as long as they also have `compton` in the file name, for example a `man` page.